# Detect end of console output in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

```
var cp = require("child_process");

var proc = cp.spawn("cmd");
proc.stdout.on("data", data => console.log("Data:", data.toString()));
proc.stdin.write("help\n");
proc.stdin.write("help\n");
```

In the above code snippet, how would you detect when the stream has finished writing for a specific command (i.e. when, if these commands were executed in the terminal, it would show a blinking cursor that you could enter text into)?

I have tried using listening to the event `end`, but this seems only to be fired when the process finishes.

Comment: You're trying to spawn a command prompt, issue commands through it, and then detect when those commands complete? This sounds like a bad idea, can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm just using command prompt as an example, I'm actually trying to interact with `ghci` - which can be run as Haskell's repl. I want to know when the output from a command issued in the repl through node.js has finished outputing.

Comment: @thing789 you can output a command from your child process to your master process and listen for it via stdout.

Comment: My problem is that when listening to the command via `proc.stdout.on("data", () => ...)`, the data event is emitted more than once for a command which outputs longer text. I want to detect when the command has finished outputting to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive way to know, unless the program you're executing has a well-defined output format (e.g. newline-delimited JSON, XML, etc.). Either way, you will have to perform some kind of parsing (and possible buffering) of the program output.

Comment: If I run a command on terminal (e.g. command prompt), it seems to know when a command has finished executing because it shows a blinking cursor. How would it do that?

Comment: At that point, the command prompt is still running, and it's just using another protocol to notify you that the executed command has completed. That protocol is "show the command prompt." What @mscdex is saying is that you need to implement a software version of your eyes, by parsing the output and looking for that command prompt. I'm not too familiar with `ghci` but asking google seems to tell me that you'd be looking for `Prelude>` in the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by giving stdin a string which will be echoed back to you when the original command has been executed, where you know that the string executed have no unwanted effects and will probably not be outputted into stdout  with the output of the command e.g. for the given example:

```
var cp = require("child_process");

var proc = cp.spawn("cmd");
proc.stdout.on("data", data => {
    var str = data.toString();
    console.log(str)
    if(str.search("string to be detected") !== -1){
        console.log("Command finished!");
    }
});
proc.stdin.write("help\n");
proc.stdin.write("string to be detected\n");
```

Alternatively you could wait for some feature of the response which indicates the end of the command output such as a newline or a new prompt, as suggested by @mesdex and @user866762

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can just do this:

```js
proc.stdout.on('end', () => { /* we're done here */ })
```